# Key-Range does not stay rounded when put into dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, floating-point, key, rounding

I am trying to bin the values in my data and put them in a dictionary in Python.

However, after creating the dictionary, its key-range produces weird aritfacts, like 0.6900000000000001 instead of 0.69. They only appear after creating the dictionary, though, the initial array "key_range" has only normal values. Therefore, the last two lines of my code produce KeyErrors, since the value 0.69 does not exist.

Does anyone know what is going on? Is it wrong to use the zip-function? Can I not create a functioning dictionary like this? I suppose I can iterate through the key values and round them manually, but I imagine there are more elegant solutions.

Cheers, and thanks

```
import numpy as np

key_range = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01) # these numbers are perfectly OK.
values = [0] * len(key_range)
value_dict = dict(zip(key_range, values)) # and here, I get weird artifacts.
print(value_dict)
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    value_dict[data[i]] = value_dict[data[i]] + 1
```

Comment: Please see https://0.30000000000000004.com/

Comment: I get that these artifacts exist. It just confuses me that apparently they dont exist after the numpy arange function, and then they do after the dictionary is created. (or at least they are not printed when I print the keyrange, but when I print the dictionary they are.)

Comment: Okay I just checked that, and the artifact do in fact exist. They are just not printed. 
I suppose watching out for this kind of problem when using numpy arange on floating point numbers ist just something I have to learn. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I suppose I can iterate through the key values and round them manually, but I imagine there are more elegant solutions.*. For what it is worth, you can fix them within your expression that creates value_dict, which still looks pretty elegant to me:

```
value_dict = dict(zip(map(lambda x: round(x,2), key_range), values))
```

Comment: Thank you. That's certainly more elegant than another loop.